# running script in mssql local server group via batch file

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, cmd

A created a mssql local server group containing all our production server. And now i am planning to automate running the script via batch file, is there a way to connect/run my script in my local server group via batch file?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking but maybe this will help https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/administer-multiple-servers-using-central-management-servers

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the [sqlcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sqlcmd-utility) command line utility in your batch file to connect and execute queries and / or SQL script files.

Comment: problem is when i tried to connect using sqlcmd it is connected to my local database and not in LOCAL SERVER GROUP that i created.

Comment: @zaxxx, you can specify the server to connect to via `-S` switch (it's case sensitive, make sure it's a capital S).

Comment: HI Roger, Problem is what server i will but in -S since local server group compose of many different servers.